# R: machine learning based on text classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-classification

I am working on a problem where I have a data-set (analysis)  like this:

```
Description                     Code
---------------                ----------
abc def ijk                    100
def  pqr                       200
abc def rst                    100
pqr mno                        300
```

I have this data-set of around 200 000 records with 150 distinct codes.
I need to make an ML recommendation system which based on the incoming description text suggest in which code bucket it should go based on previous allocations.

I did some of the ground-work in R using Text Mining (tm package) to clean the text, fetched word-frequencies (findFreqTerms) and word-associations (findAssocs) and calculated the probabilities in SQL of those word-associations to go into a particular code, by that I can see that there is a pattern between word-association as you can see below.

```
SELECT description, 
code, 
cnt descdcnt, 
sum(cnt) over (PARTITION BY description) desccnt, 
cnt*100/sum(cnt) over (PARTITION BY description) perc
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%abc%pqr%' THEN 'abc pqr' 
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%def%mno%' THEN 'def mno'
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%xyz%ijk%' THEN 'xyz ijk'
    ................................................
    ELSE 'other' END description, code,  count(*) cnt
    FROM analysis 
    GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%abc%pqr%' THEN 'abc pqr' 
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%def%mno%' THEN 'def mno'
    WHEN lower(description) LIKE '%xyz%ijk%' THEN 'xyz ijk' 
    ...........................................
    ELSE 'other' END, code

)
ORDER BY perc DESC;


Description      Code      descdcnt    desccnt    perc
-------------------------------------------------------
abc pqr          100         988        1000      98.8
xyz mno          200         935        1000      93.5
def wqr          300         854        1000      85.4
```

I want to develop an ML which can learn from above patterns and suggest a recommendation with above 80% probability. I tried Naive Bayes algo in R (train on 70%, test on 30%) but accuracy is pretty poor, validated with CrossTable.

How to approach this problem with ML in R? I just need pointers, rest I can dig in.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a programming question - you'd be better off asking for advice over on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out some bayesian learning approach here. From your description it looks like as if you will keep on getting your "description" and you may want to account for any future deviation from observed behavior. For trying out bayesian you can take your "prec" from SQL as prior probability.

Rest even before you try out any other algo it will be better to understand why naive bayes is an overfit? In plain language it means that your train and test data are different. Can you look into data and try to find why it is such a behavior. Starting point could be making sure imp terms (from naive bayes on complete dataset) distributed evenly in train and test dataset. Naive bayes does mostly good on text data.

PS: Expecting 80%+ probability will be very difficult but do try (Dont want to shatter your hopes)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I took the random sample (70% train& 30% test) and verified the distribution proportion on train & test data as follows.
{
--------------------------------------
prop.table(table(analysis_train_labels))
analysis_train_labels
  100                200              300              400             500    
0.07492420 0.05168699 0.07483388 0.06433133 0.35651893  

prop.table(table(analysis_test_labels))
analysis_test_labels
  100               200              300               400             500       
0.07574435 0.05322576 0.07550351 0.06415390 0.35698588    }

Comment: What I meant was to take all data, run naive bayes, look into most imp terms (say abc is one of them) then you can do stratified sampling to split train n test to make sure your model doesn't overfilts.e.g  using data.table `test_ind <- analysis[, sample(.I, round(0.3*.N), FALSE),by="abc,pqr,xyz"]$V1`

Comment: Thanks again, I got your point, let me try that.
Based on the word-frequencies (abc) & word-association (abc pqr), I can see in my SQL analysis that probability increases with word-association (>90%), but I learnt it manually, I want my algo to learn it itself from existing data and then make recommendations on incoming data. Working on that...